# Mixed encoding and make everything UTF-8

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have some texts that has various encoding, For example the following text, has mixed encoding of UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1:

```
Ù…Ø­ØªÙˆØ§ÛŒ Ù…ÛŒÚ©Ø³ Ø´Ø¯Ù‡ و بخش سالم
```

But I want all these to become UTF-8, that means the sections that has UTF-8 encoding left, and the other strings become UTF-8, for example, above text should be output as:

```
محتوای میکس شده و بخش سالم
```

I used different ways, use the `iconv` function in PHP and use following class:

https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8

But none of them gave me the correct output, And always some part of the text become question mark like `???????`.

What is the best way to convert mixed encoding to UTF-8 without any damage?

Edit:

Row bytes of mixed text:

```
c399e280a6c398c2adc398c2aac399cb86c398c2a7c39bc59220c399e280a6c39bc592c39ac2a9c398c2b320c398c2b4c398c2afc399e280a120d98820d8a8d8aed8b420d8b3d8a7d984d985
```

Correct text:

```
محتوای میکس شده و بخش سالم
```

Comment: Are these actually *mixed encodings*, or mojibake (incorrectly converted text) mixed with non-mojibake? Either way, you're pretty much screwed.

Comment: These are mixed encodings.

Comment: Give us a sample of the raw bytes and what text you expect that to correspond to. Also, how did it end up like that, and can't you fix it on the source?

Comment: Sample text in my question is what is that and second is what must be, do you need more text? These comes from old database and I don't know how this happened. I shouldn't make any changes to database.

Comment: Give us the *raw bytes*. In PHP: `echo bin2hex($string)`.

Comment: Added to question, thanks

Comment: Is this content coming from a database?

Comment: Yes, it comes from a database @Oussama

Comment: That sample confirms that you have a UTF-8 encoded string literally containing the characters Ù, …, Ø etc., and also the characters ل ,م etc. Well, yes, you're pretty screwed. Looks like incorrectly encoded Window-1252 mojibake. If you're absolutely sure the text is supposed to be Arabic, you can probably pick out the character ranges which are not Arabic and fix their encoding with `iconv('UTF-8', 'Windows-1252', $substr)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part of your string is Windows-1252 mojibake, meaning at some point a UTF-8 string was interpreted as Windows-1252 and converted from that wrong assumption to UTF-8. That can be reversed by transcoding the string from UTF-8 to Windows-1252, which results in the correct UTF-8 sequence of the original. To apply that to only the subset of the text that is messed up, you can use a regex to, for instance, apply the transformation to only non-Arabic parts of the text:

```
// sample data
$str_hex = 'c399e280a6c398c2adc398c2aac399cb86c398c2a7c39bc59220c399e280a6c39bc592c39ac2a9c398c2b320c398c2b4c398c2afc399e280a120d98820d8a8d8aed8b420d8b3d8a7d984d985';
// actual string
$str = hex2bin($str_hex);

echo 'Messed up: ', $str, PHP_EOL;  // Ù…Ø­ØªÙˆØ§ÛŒ Ù…ÛŒÚ©Ø³ Ø´Ø¯Ù‡ و بخش سالم

$fixed = preg_replace_callback(
    '/\\P{Arabic}+/u',  // matches non-Arabic sequences
    function (array $m) { return iconv('UTF-8', 'Windows-1252', $m[0]); }, 
    $str
);

echo 'Fixed: ', $fixed;  // محتوای میکس شده و بخش سالم
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching around in many questions here, and finding many "mixed encoding" solutions, none of them actually worked for my case.

But here's how I solved it. The simplest of all:
Export/Convert as **UTF-8** on the latest **Notepad++**. It actually converted all lines without errors, contrary to many packages (such as **iconv** etc.).

Comment: Your solution will not work for dynamic contents such as a website!

Answer (score -1):

Regarding the answear of @Nulled confirming that the data are coming from a database, I can confirm that the problem is coming from a bad encoding of your table or database.
I got this problem before and I fixed it by forcing the database/table encoding juste before getting my data using this query (you need to update it to your database/table encoding):

```
SET NAMES latin1;
```

For example:

```
$this->db->query('SET NAMES latin1;');
$this->db->query('SELECT * FROM table')->result();
```

Comment: That won't help given the sample data the OP provided.

Comment: The problem is mixed encoding not Unicode encoding, if I set the names on latin1, correct strings gets damage.

Comment: Did you try it?
Did you try to combine it with utf8_encode()?